# Nexus S not showing up on DDMS

Tags: android

I am using Windows 7/64 bit HP laptop

I have installed both Java 32 bit as well as java 64 bit. Installed Android environment.
Installed Google Version 4 driver from Android AVD  and SDK Manager.

Windows automatically installed the nexus driver and it shows up in my computer->manage->device manager->Storage->Android UMS composite USB device.

Windows shows the removable storage for the connected Nexus S device.
but don't see anything on DDMS for device neither does "adb devices" 
shows anything.

Answer (score 3):

Did you enable USB debugging under Settings -> Applicatons -> Development? If you didn't, the phone won't show on DDMS

Answer (score 0):

Check that USB Debugging is enabled in your Application Settings.